# filling combo box using LINQ query (distinct)

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, distinct

I have a combocox the name is "cmbModel" I want to fill the database with two different values in a table.
This is what I have done:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (LINQSQLDataContext db = new LINQSQLDataContext())
            {
                cmbModel.DisplayMember = "szModel";
                cmbModel.DataSource = db.VehEcus.ToList<VehEcu>();
            }
        }
```

this will fill my cmbModel with szModel column of my table but I want to avoid repeating , how can I use "`distinct`" in query to achieve my goal?
and also I want to show 2 items of my table like "`modelID-szModel`" in my combobox

Thanks

Comment: _"and also I want to show 2 items of my table like "modelID-szModel" in my combobox"_ you have to explain this better.

Comment: I mean at the moment I can only show szModel in my combo box but I have another column (modelId) that I want to show modelId and szModel in this format (modelId-szModel) in combo box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show a single column anyway you could select that column and use `Distinct`:

```
cmbModel.DataSource = db.InfoProg_VehEcus.Select(x => x.szModel).Distinct();
```

Comment: Dear Tim Thanks,it works but if I want to havesth like (modelId-szModel) how can I write it?
sth like (y => y.lModelId x => x.szModel)

Comment: You can use any string methods in Select, f.e. String.Format if you want to concatenate two columns.

Comment: `(x => x.IModelId + "-" + x.szModel)`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Distinct() at any point after your query. I recommend doing it before you enumerate.

To create the custom modelID-szModel field, you can enumerate the query using AsEnumerable(), then create an anonymous type and use String.Format to concatenate your values into your new field.

```
        using (LINQSQLDataContext c = new LINQSQLDataContext ())
        {
            var items = c.VehEcus.Select(t => new
            {
                a = t.szModel,
                b = t.modelID
            }).Distinct()
            .AsEnumerable().Select(t => new
            {
                displayMember = String.Format("{0}-{1}", t.a, t.b)
            });

            cmbModel.DisplayMember = "displayMember";
            cmbModel.DataSource = items.ToList();
        }
```